# How to get values from multidimensional array, searching by name?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I want to check each subarray for `item2` as the value in the first element (index `0`).
If so, I want to return the second element's value (index `1`).

This is my multidimensional array:

```
$arr = Array
(
    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item',
            1 => 3,
            2 => 20,
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item2',
            1 => 1,
            2 => 21,
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item3',
            1 => 4,
            2 => 26,
        ),

    20 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item4',
            1 => 1,
            2 => 39,
        ),

    22 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item1',
            1 => 10,
            2 => 39,
        ),
     23 => Array
        (
            0 => 'item2',
            1 => 11,
            2 => 39,
        )
);
```

The expected result is: `[1,11]`

I used this function but it doesn't return all of the results:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {

    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, use can not have multiple array elements with same key  (item2=>1,item2=>11) , but you can collect all values [1] (1,11)

For example

```
$arr = // your array()
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    if (isset($row[0]) && $row[0] == 'item2') {
        $res[] = $row[1];
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```